# jython - why '==' return true but 'is' return false

Tags: jython-2.7

I am start use jython2.7.0 now, but there has little different between python2.7.15.

for example, In python

a = "hello", b = "hello", "a is b" and "a == b" will return True.

but In jython2.7.0 "a is b" return False, "a == b" return True, does anyone knows why ??

```
>>>jython
>>>
>>>a = "hello"
>>>b = "hello"
>>>
>>>a is b
>>>False
>>>
>>>a == b
>>>True
>>>
>>>a = 1
>>>b = 1
>>> a is b
>>>True
```

Comment: If Jython is Python, it should be same, right?? in Python, because b's value is equal a, therefore it will point to a. It is undoubtly.

But Jython is not, because even b's value is equal to a,  "a is b" is return False.

But if a&b is int. e.g. a =1, b=1, "a is b" will return True, I guess does it is relevent to Java's String compare( == and equals())

Comment: I stand corrected.  Why I don't like Python.

Comment: What makes this different?? I just don't get it(like the picture my post (Code example.))

Comment: Don't post pictures of _text_.  Post the text in code mark-up.

Comment: The [language reference](http://www.jython.org/docs/reference/indexprogress.html) to the Jython project simply points to the Python project.  If they are not semantically identical then it is a bug in the Jython implementation perhaps?  Report it to the project http://www.jython.org/docs/bugs.html

Comment: Reproduced using Python and JPython tools at https://www.tutorialspoint.com, and they do indeed differ for the same script.  Seems like a bug to me, but intuitively the JPython behavior makes sense to me, while the Python behavior bemuses me - like most of Python - nasty language IMO.  Nonetheless if JPython is intended to be semantically identical to Python, then it is JPython that is wrong.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jython, just guessing. Maybe `==` compares values, where `is` compares references? In Java terms - `==` vs `equals`?

Comment: @Maroun But if two identical Strings are contained in the same compilation unit, then they should point to the same reference.

Comment: @AdamHorvath I'm not sure how string pool works in Jython, I was just guessing.

Comment: @Clifford
Thanks, you help alot, I have report this bug to jython.org/docs/bugs.html. If it has any response, I will post on it to let everyone know.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_jython_online.php  ===> it is a online jython editor , everybody who be interested can play some jython method on it.

your sincerely.

Comment: Dear all, Mr Stefan has answer this question on bugs.jython.org - issue2716, there is his response - 

Python's "is" corresponds to Java's == and Python's == corresponds to Java's equals. So you see that the same string literal created twice should not be the same object. CPython applies some memory optimization here called string interning. Jython uses interning as well, but currently not on literals. AFAIK it uses it on dictionary keys only.

More detail is on - http://bugs.jython.org/issue2716

Thanks and best regard.